# Problems with class initialization

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, initialization, initializer

I think it's a simple problem but a head scratcher.
I'm getting a `....has no initializers` error when there actually are initializers.

Here is my code:

(Edit:  I've updated the PatientData class to include all the additional variables.  I didn't think they made a difference in figuring out the problem, so for the sake of brevity I left them out.)

Data Structures

```swift
class PatientData: Identifiable, ObservableObject
{
    let id = UUID()
    
    @Published var patientName: String = "Name"
    @Published var patientAge: String = "Age"
    @Published var patientDOB: String = "DOB"
    @Published var patientPhone: String = "Phone"
    @Published var patientAddress: PatientAddress

    struct PatientAddress
    {
        var patientStreetAddress: String = "Street"
        var patientCity: String = "City"
        var patientState: String = "State"
        var patientZip: String = "Zip"
        
        init(patientStreetAddress: String, patientCity: String, patientState: String, patientZip: String)
        {
            self.patientStreetAddress = patientStreetAddress
            self.patientCity = patientCity
            self.patientState = patientState
            self.patientZip = patientZip
        }
    }
    
    @Published var facilityName: String = "Facility"
    @Published var facilityRoom: String = "Room Number"
    @Published var facilityFloor: String = "Floor"
    @Published var facilityPhoneNumber: String = "Phone Number"
    
    init(patientName: String, patientAge: String, patientDOB: String, patientPhone: String, patientAddress: PatientAddress, facilityName: String, facilityRoom: String, facilityFloor: String, facilityPhoneNumber: String)
    {
        self.patientName = patientName
        self.patientAge = patientAge
        self.patientDOB = patientDOB
        self.patientPhone = patientPhone
        self.patientAddress = patientAddress
        self.facilityName = facilityName
        self.facilityRoom = facilityRoom
        self.facilityFloor = facilityFloor
        self.facilityPhoneNumber = facilityPhoneNumber
    }
    init() {}
}
```

Content View

```swift
struct ContentView: View
{
    @ObservedObject var patient = PatientData()
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that:

```
PatientData()
```

is an equivalent of:

```
PatientData.init()
```

Which means that if you want to create your PatientData this way:

```
@ObservedObject var patient = PatientData()
```

you need to provide a matching init method (it can be empty as all your `@Published` properties have already a default value):

```
init() { }
```

---

**EDIT**

Looking at your full code, it seems like one of your properties has no initial value:

```
@Published var patientAddress: PatientAddress
```

An empty init will work only when all your properties are already initialised, which means you need to assign some value to your `patientAddress`:

```
@Published var patientAddress = PatientAddress()
```

However, for this to work, you'd need to add an empty init in `PatientAddress` as well:

```
struct PatientAddress {
    ...
    init() {}
}
```

---

**NOTE**

All your code could be much simpler without all these initialisers. If you only use empty init methods you don't have to declare them (they are auto-generated for structs if there are no other initialisers):

```
class PatientData: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    let id = UUID()

    @Published var patientName: String = "Name"
    @Published var patientAge: String = "Age"
    @Published var patientDOB: String = "DOB"
    @Published var patientPhone: String = "Phone"
    @Published var patientAddress: PatientAddress = PatientAddress()

    @Published var facilityName: String = "Facility"
    @Published var facilityRoom: String = "Room Number"
    @Published var facilityFloor: String = "Floor"
    @Published var facilityPhoneNumber: String = "Phone Number"
}

extension PatientData {
    struct PatientAddress {
        var patientStreetAddress: String = "Street"
        var patientCity: String = "City"
        var patientState: String = "State"
        var patientZip: String = "Zip"
    }
}
```

Also, Swift can infer types automatically. You don't usually have to declare types explicitly:

```
@Published var patientPhone = "Phone"
@Published var patientAddress = PatientAddress()
```

Comment: I left the body of the initialization  out.  Please see above.

Comment: @Cubert Still, if you add `init() {}` to your class it should work. However, by the error you're getting it looks like you didn't show us the *whole* `PatientData` class and you left out some important code.

Comment: Thanks!  All that worked.  And I simplified my code as you suggested.
